# To get the current URL to the next page by PHP's sessions

Tags: php, session, get, url

**How can you use the part after the question mark in the url which comes as a output of the following variable?**

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
if (0 !== $_GET['question_id'] && isset( $_GET['question_id'] ) ) {                                              
    $result = pg_execute( $dbconn, "query_fetch", array( $_GET['question_id'] ) ); 
}
if (isset( $_SERVER['question_id'] ) ) {
    $result = pg_execute( $dbconn, "query_fetch", array( $_SERVER['question_id'] ) ); 
}
                                                        // problem here!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the URL parameters of an URL, try the [`parse_str` function](http://docs.php.net/parse_str):

```
$query = preg_match('/\?([^#]*)/', $url, $match) ? $match[1] : '';  // extract query from URL
parse_str($query, $params);
```

---

**Edit**    Here’s an example:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/?foo&bar=&baz=quux';
$query = preg_match('/\?([^#]*)/', $url, $match) ? $match[1] : '';
parse_str($query, $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["bar"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["baz"]=>
  string(4) "quux"
}
```

Comment: Please, see my reply to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may want to use a page's referer.

http://archives.devshed.com/forums/php-windows-119/get-referer-with-php-2329588.html

Comment: Please, see the edit in the question. Thank you for your answer which put me in the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `$_GET` equivilant of the Referer by using:

```
$parts = explode("?", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$get = parse_str(end($parts))
```

Whenever you use the variable `$_SERVER`, make sure that you are using one of the predefined variables. `$_SERVER['question_id']` isn't likely to be in the `$_SERVER` array.

```
......
// These variables aren't normally present:
if (isset( $_SERVER['question_id'] ) ) {
    $result = pg_execute( $dbconn, "query_fetch", array( $_SERVER['question_id'] ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Note that the query can also contain a plain `?`.

Answer (score 0):

**Reply to Gumbo's answer**

I understand your answer as follows

```
$pattern = '/\?([^#]*)/';
$subject = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$query = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match) ? $match[1] : '';  // extract query from URL
parse_str($query, $params);
$question_id = explode( "=", $query );           // to get the parameter
echo "This is the output: " . $question_id[1];
```

### **How can you access the variable $params without the use of explode?**

I run the following commands unsuccessfully

```
print_r( $params );
var_dump( $params );
```

The former gives me *Array()*, while the latter nothing.

Comment: `$params` is aready an associative array of the URL parameters.